# Retrieve Checked Checkboxes with PHP and post

Tags: php

Important things first.... My english is not the best so i would kindly ask you to help me and overlook my failures in english language.... Thank you.

I know this Question was asked many times before but all these answers doesn't help me. So im asking myself.

I have my Form with 6 Checkboxes which looks like this:

```
<form id="product_form" method="post">    
    <input type="checkbox" name="edges" value="yes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="light" value="yes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="color_change" value="yes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="white" value="yes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="printed" value="yes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="legs" value="yes">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you now click on Submit, the form will be submitted to my PHP script which looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['edges'] == "yes"){
        $edges == "yes";
    } else {
        $edges == "no";
    }
}
```

I have this Code foreach of my Checkboxes because i know, checkboxes will only be submitted if they are checked but in my script, if i dump $edges, the checkbox is always active if i check it or not that doesn't matter.

I Already tried to check for isset($_POST['edges']) but that doesnt work either.
While i searched for a solution i fell over "Checkbox Arrays" but i think this way is working better in my case because i want to write all of them into a Database so i would make an Array out of my Checkboxes only to convert them back in single variables.

I dont know what im doing wrong here.... I just assume that you can help me in this case and im sure its just a minor mistake but i cant find this mistake on my own... so please guide me the way to a working Form! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see from looking at your code is your use of the equality operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`) when setting your variables.

This:

```
$edges == 'yes';
```

Should be:

```
$edges = 'yes';
```

It's hard to tell from your question whether your issue simply comes down to this.

You state you're using that code for each of your checkboxes. All of your checkbox conditions can go inside the single submit `isset()` block.

E.g.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {  
    // test for edges...
    // test for light...
}
```

Given your markup, you should be using `isset()` for the checkboxes. If you post the form and those checkboxes aren't checked, they won't be set in `$_POST`.

Complete example:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $edges = ( isset( $_POST['edges'] ) ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    $light = ( isset( $_POST['light'] ) ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    // . . .
}
```

While the approach above using single variables works, there's a much cleaner way of writing this with arrays.

Array example HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox[]" value="edges">
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox[]" value="light">
. . .
```

Array example PHP:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    // Each checkbox option should default to no.
    $checkboxes = array(
        'edges' => 'no',
        'light' => 'no',
        // . . . don't forget to add all your options here.
    );

    // Let's make sure we have some checkboxes posted.
    if (  ! empty( $_POST['myCheckbox'] ) ) {

        // Loop through each checked option.
        foreach ( (array) $_POST['myCheckbox'] as $checked ) {

            // If the checked option exists in our checkbox array, update value to yes.
            if ( array_key_exists( $checked, $checkboxes ) ) {
                $checkboxes[ $checked ] = 'yes';
            }
        }
    }

    // Do stuff with your checkbox values here...
}
```

Comment: Very well explained